# how to get last day of current month in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have following code:

```
var l_date = new Date();
l_date.setDate(30);
l_date.setHours(23);
l_date.setMinutes(59);
l_date.setSeconds(59);


l_date;
```

but I want programmatically to set last day of month since it is not constant by using a function to retrieve this data, how to get that in mongo???

Comment: you setting value using javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var userMonth = 0; // January
var userYear = 2016

var d = new Date(userYear, userMonth + 1, 0);

d -> Last day of the userMonth
```

> Trying to achieve the Last day of the month via Javascript

For MongoDb

```
var dayNo = 3

var answer = new Date(ISODate().getTime() + 1000 * 3600 * 24 * dayNo )
```

Here answer will be the third day from Current Date.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone want to calculate this using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), then this can help.
In MongoDB 4.2, was include `$$NOW`, a variable that can be accessed in aggregation pipelines which returns the current time as an ISODate.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      monthEnd: {
        $subtract: [
          {
            $dateFromParts: {
              "year": {
                $year: "$$NOW"
              },
              "month": {
                $add: [
                  {
                    $month: "$$NOW"
                  },
                  1
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          86400000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As this answer is being created in July of 2020, then the result is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "monthEnd": ISODate("2020-07-31T00:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d= new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth()+1, 0);
return d.getDate();
```

JavaScript code to get number of days in month that will be last day of month